# How to Get 10 from this link (https://google.com/?ib=10)

Tags: javascript

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtXo5.png)
I have this link in (note this link not from search URL)
`var link = https://google.com/?ib=10` in main.js file.
Now how to get that **10** from this link in javaScript on Page load

I have tried this way

```
var link1 = link;
const url3 = new URLSearchParams(link1);
    const ur = url3.get("ib");
    var finaltgid = ur;
    alert(ur);
```

But its not working may be this code only work when we use `window.location.search`
Instead of `var or const`

Comment: Hey, this question is answered here with more details. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/get-the-values-from-the-get-parameters-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Sir, I want to get from var not from Search url

Answer (score 0):

urlsearchparams does not parse full url, you need to pass only query part, like this:

```js
var link = 'https://google.com/?ib=10';
const url = new URLSearchParams(new URL(link).search);
const ib = url.get("ib");
console.log(ib);
```

Comment: Showing this error Failed to Construct URL : invalid URL

Answer (score 0):

URLSearchParams only accepts the actual query part in the constructor. You are including the full link.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: For a given link you can just supply the link in place of document.location (which directly fetches the pages current location)

Considering this as Vanilla JS. You can do the following.

```
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;

let ib = parseInt(params.get('ib')); // is the number 10
```

Note, using the `parseInt` to get the value as a number.